# How to sum two columns in query on Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following model on my postgresql database:

```
class UrlXML(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    url = models.TextField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_index=True)
    run_last_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    run_frequency = models.IntegerField(default=24)
```

Every hour I need to get from database url that need to be downloaded based when on my current time and if the last time it ran was higher then the frequency.

I manage to create the raw query, but I can't manage to create it in Django Queryset.

Here is the following query:

```
select (run_last_time + INTERVAL '1 hours' * run_frequency), run_frequency, NOW(), run_last_time from urlxml where is_active=True and (run_last_time + INTERVAL '1 hours' * run_frequency) <= NOW();
```

Example:

Current time is 2017-04-03 11:00:00

I have two url in database:

Url A: Ran last time 2017-04-03 08:00:00 and its frequency is 6 hours

Url B: Ran last time 2017-04-02 11:00:00 and its frequency is 24 hours

When I execute the function at 2017-04-03 11:00:00 (within the margin of + and - 30 minutes), it must bring me the Url B only, 'cause the last time it ran was 24 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution using the extra in the Queryset.

Here it is:

```
UrlXML.objects.filter(is_active=True).extra(
    where={"run_last_time + INTERVAL '1 hours' * run_frequency <= NOW()"}
)
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do this, but is the only one I manage to find.

If there are better ways to do it, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I think you can use `F expressions`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters

Answer (score 0):

If you were to change your model slightly, you could use [`Query Expressions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions).

```py
# models.py
class UrlXML(models.Model):
    ...
    run_frequency = models.DurationField(default=timedelta(hours=24))
```

```py
UrlXML.objects \
    .annotate(expires=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('run_last_time') + F('run_frequency'),
        output_field=DateTimeField())) \
    .filter(expires__lte=datetime.now())
```

This solutions is also a bit more robust, as you can use [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta) instead of hours only.